# Zend_Paginator for Categories

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I have used Zend_Paginator in my Index action , this show all my catalog :

```
public function indexAction()
{
   Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('/pagination.phtml');
    $pages = new Application_Model_DbTable_Catalog();

    $num = 10;
    $page = $this->_getParam('page');

    $select = $pages->select();
    $result = $this->view->table = $pages->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array($result));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($num);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    $paginator->setView($this->view);
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
}
```

It works perfectly, now I have CategoryAction, it's sort my catalog by category

```
public function categoryAction()
{
    $id = intval($this->_getParam('id', 0));
    if ($id > 0) {
        $catalog = new Application_Model_DbTable_Catalog();
        $this->view->catalog = $catalog->getByCategoryId($id);
        и
        $category = new Application_Model_DbTable_Categories();
        $this->view->category = $category->getById($id);



    }
```

So I can't understand how to add Pagination to this action,
                               Help me, Pleaaasssseeeeeee:-(,
P.S. sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is a better/easier way to do this.

Pagination starts with your database query. You are using DbTable models so it's very easy in ZF1 to setup the adapter.

```
<?php 

class Application_Model_DbTable_Catalog extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'catalog'
    /*
     * This method returns a paginator adapter with a fetchAll($where = null, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null)
     * paginator adapter will supply the values for $offset and $limit
     */
    public function getPagedCatalog() 
    {
        $select = $this->select(); //put anything you need into $select
        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);//the paginator adapter in place of the fetchAll().

        return $adapter;
    {
}

<?php 

class Application_Model_DbTable_Categories extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'categories'

    /*
     * This method returns a paginator adapter with a fetchAll($where = $id, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null)
     * paginator adapter will supply the values for $offset and $limit
     */
    public function getPagedCatagories($id) 
    {
        $select = $this->select(); //put anything you need into $select
        $select->where('catagory_id = ?', $id);//you may need to build a join for this to work how you want it to, depends on your table structure.
        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);//the paginator adapter in place of the fetchAll().

        return $adapter;
    {
}
```

now your models will return paginator adapters with the contents of these tables available. `Zend_Paginator` will automatically supply the `$limit` and `$offset` parameters to the query so that each page will perform a query. The whole table will not be stored in memory with this adapter.

Now your `indexAction()` may look like:

```
public function indexAction()
{
   Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('/pagination.phtml');
    $pages = new Application_Model_DbTable_Catalog();
    $adapter = $pages->getPagedCatalog(); //get adapter from model

    $page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);//a default of page 1 prevents possible unusual behavior when no page number is set.

    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage('10');
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    //$paginator->setView($this->view); This line is likely not needed
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
}
```

and your `categoryAction()` might work like:

```
public function categoryAction()
{
    $page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);
    $id = intval($this->_getParam('id', 0));
    if ($id > 0) {
        $category = new Application_Model_DbTable_Categories();
        $adapter = $category->getPagedCatagories($id);
        //same as above
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage('10');
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        //$paginator->setView($this->view); This line is likely not needed, unless you have multiple view objects.
        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    } else {
        //do some other stuff...
    }
}
```

if you get crazy and want to use your own mapper classes to base a paginator adapter on you can extend the adapter class by overriding `getItems()`, something like:

```
<?php

class Music_Model_Paginator_Track extends Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect
{
    //override getItems()
    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        $rows = parent::getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage);

        $albums = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $album = new Music_Model_Mapper_Track();//use this class to turn each $row into an object                
            $albums[] = $album->createEntity($row); //build the new entity objects
        }
        //returns an array of entity objects to the paginator
        return $albums;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.